# Are drive-by downloads and installs a significant threat to an average modern Android or Firefox for Windows user?

Tags: windows, android, firefox, drive-by-download

Today I learned that drive-by downloads and drive-by installations are or have been a thing. Yet there's something very counterintuitive about them if considered a real threat for modern smartphone or modern mainstream web browser users. For clarity, by these drive-by events I mean malware getting to your device just by you navigating to a URL with a web browser and then being automatically executed by some mechanism that is not and never was in your control.

It seems to me that these modern platforms are very isolated execution environments and also only offer very restricted APIs to the system by default. For example Android operating system when used with its default settings and without explicitly applying any tricks, will refuse to install or execute any programs from sources that are not officially recognized as trusted. Similarly modern desktop web browsers such as Firefox 113.0.1 seem to make it very obvious when stuff is downloaded (i.e. a circular progress animation appears and finally a dialog informs that a thing is now in the default downloads directory) or some curious APIs are accessed (e.g. browser settings dialog opens, informing that the site wants to use location or microphone or whatever).

I know the browser will download and execute any JavaScript included or referenced in any HTML document it receives upon navigating to a URL, but those scripts are run in an isolated JS runtime environment within the browser and the browser doesn't allow it any significant access to the underlying system by default. I also know that the browser will download any other file too that is served to the request, but if it's not web content it will just go to whatever is the default downloaded files path in your system and that's it; no automatic execution of random stuff should occur. I also know that threats from malware can emerge from a set of events over a period of time instead of having to originate from a single site visit or download, i.e. a piece of malware may find its way to the system from one place and be activated by some other mechanism at a later point in time, but that's also not what I'm asking here.

What is there really in these described environments (say e.g. Android 13 on a Samsung flagship model, and Firefox 113.0.1 on some Windows 11 PC) that would allow a drive-by download and installation of malware? Is it enough to not open suspicious files from the downloads directory to stay reasonably secure or not?

Comment: You only see the "public side" of those systems but forget that you can combine vulnerabilities: thus the download will not use the Firefox downloader interface and the Android installation will not install an APK file, instead they use a vulnerability to bypass the limitations implemented in Firefox or Android. Such are attacks are pretty common and you hear about such attacks several times a year.

Comment: I see. I suppose the threat is quite generic then. As in the same can be said about anything; a vulnerability may emerge when someone clever enough happens to find a way to do something malicious that anyone didn't think of preemptively counter-measuring yet. Threats come and go everywhere, and all one can do is to keep patching when patches come available. But there's no inherent feature in these platforms that would make them especially vulnerable to this special kind of threat.